# Seeking more streamlined way to specify the color of a label

Tags: reactjs, sass, colors

In my React component, I've added a `Label.tsx` component that ultimately renders this:

```
return <label className={styles[color]}>{text}</label>
```

This works to change color because there's a companion `Label.module.scss` file with entries like this:

```
.black {
  color: $black;
}

.blue {
  color: $blue;
}

.red {
  color: $red;
}
```

FYI `Label.module.scss` imports `_colors.scss`, which defines the color constants like:

```
$black: black; // ie. #000000
$blue: blue;   // ie. #0000FF
$red: red;     // ie. #FF0000
```

Having to explicitly add all of the colors to `Label.module.scss` seems redundant but it's the only way I know to make it work.  Is there an alternative approach I could use to directly reference the colors in `_colors.scss` ?